# Mysql query poorly optimized

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I am not expert in sql and I need help with the following query. It is poorly optmized and it takes too long time to execute.
Is it possible to replace `IN()` with `JOIN()` to speed up the query?
How to do it?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   shop_orders 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT orders_id 
              FROM   shop_orders_data 
              WHERE  closed = '1' /*AND backorder='0'*/) 
       AND id IN (SELECT orders_id 
                  FROM   shop_orders_products 
                  WHERE  products_id IN (SELECT id 
                                         FROM   shop_products 
                                         WHERE  artno = '120000' 
                                                 OR name LIKE '%120000%')) 
ORDER  BY created DESC
```

Comment: Try adding your table structures and key relationships to your post (and accepting answers to your previous questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select so.*
from shop_orders as so
     join shop_orders_data as sod on sod.orders_id = so.id
     join (select orders_id 
           from   shop_orders_products as sop
                  join shop_products as sp on sp.id = sop.products_id
           where  sp.artno = '120000' 
                  OR sp.name like '%120000%') as sop on sop.orders_id = so.id
where 
  sod.closed = '1'
order by so.created desc
```

Comment: Just updated it so you're joining on an already reduced query result. this should make the join operation faster since it will have less rows to go through.

The main idea here is that in your first query you were effectively performing a query for each line in your table. Here, you'll be performing a merge operation and THEN querying the table to see if it meets the conditions specified in your where clause.

Comment: There is an extra ")" in the query. Works fine! Thanks!

Comment: Oops. sorry about that. Hope it helps you to also understand queries a bit better.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the LIKE is causing the biggest delay here...would the artno not suffice? LIKE is typically a very expensive procedure.

Comment: when you have like with a wildcard as the first character, indexes cannot be effectively used.

Comment: Thanks! It is much faster now.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT 
  s.* 
FROM 
  shop_orders s 
INNER JOIN
  shop_orders_data od 
ON 
  s.id=od.orders_id 
INNER JOIN
  shop_orders_products sop 
ON 
  s.id=sop.orders_id 
INNER JOIN 
  shop_products sp 
ON 
  sop.products_id=sp.id 
WHERE
  od.closed=1
AND 
  ( sp.artno='120000' or sp.name LIKE '%120000%' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you are on the right road - you could just have an inner join between all these tables rather than these IN operators.

```
SELECT
    so.* 
FROM 
    shop_orders so
    INNER JOIN shop_orders_data sod
       ON so.id = sod.orders_id
    INNER JOIN shop_orders_products sop
       ON sod.id = sop.orders_id
    INNER JOIN shop_products sp
       ON sop.products_id = sp.id
WHERE sod.closed = '1'
    AND (sp.artno = '120000' OR sp.name LIKE '%120000%')
```

Comment: implicit joins are a sql antipattern and should NOT be recommended in a solution.

Comment: Updated to explicit though I would not agree with describing implicit joins as an anti pattern.

Comment: This is nice. It may need `GROUP BY so.id` to remove duplicate results.